# How to delete and insert row without navigator

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with local data and I know how to edit a row, but I can't figure out how to delete or insert a row.

For insert, where do I need to place `addRowData`? In some event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following as an example :

```
var myfirstrow = {invid:"1", invdate:"2007-10-01", note:"note", amount:"200.00", tax:"10.00", total:"210.00"};
jQuery("#grid_id").addRowData("1", myfirstrow);
```

where `invid`,`invdata`,`note`,`amount`,`tax` and `total` are column names and `#grid_id` is the ID of your jqGrid to add data and

```
jQuery("#grid_id").delRowData( rowid );
```

where `rowid` is the ID of the row you want to remove

[Docs for these methods are here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

To trigger the adding / removing of rows is really your choice - you could have an add button and then prompt the user to enter the column data - then add the data to the table ....